# rviz camera view

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I set up a view in rviz to be the exact view from the camera's perspective?  For Example:  If you add the point cloud coming in from the kinect how do I set the view so I see the point cloud from the exact perspective of the kinect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11028/rviz-camera-view/) by [Jake](https://answers.ros.org/users/721/jake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To see rviz from a camera perspective:

1. Have the RVIZ Displays Pane Open (View > Displays)
2. Click "Add" to add a new display type
3. "Camera" displays your camera image with RVIZ data overlayed, "Image" will just show the raw camera image.
4. When then new display shows up in the list, fill in your "Image Topic" (e.g. /kinect/image_raw)

You should now have a working image window with RVIZ data overlaid.

You can also change the alpha blending so that just the rviz data is visible, and not the actual camera frame

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-02**:
this video tutorial might help as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4rQQ7MDcRM

**Comment by [KOMODO](https://answers.ros.org/users/45642/komodo/) on 2020-07-03**:
this youtube link is death!